# two tables with scheme t1[eid,organizer,startdate],t2[event,user,reviewdate]

Tags: mysql, database

Here eid is similar to event. I want to extract data where startdate >reviewdate or organizer =user.

I am able to get the data when i write separate query but i am not getting the correct data when i write a single query.

Herer are the queries i wrote **Separately**

> **q1**:

```
select distinct eid,
               title 
from event e,review r 
where r.user=e.organizer;
```

**q2**:

```
select distinct eid,
              title from 
event e,review r 
where e.startdate>r.reviewdate;
```

when i write a single query as

***Q**:

```
select distinct eid,title 
from event e,review r 
 where r.user=e.organizer or e.startdate>r.reviewdate;
```

I am getting wrong answer

Comment: start by using join and not comma separated FROM clause, and what does it mean wrong? can you provide a full [mre]

Comment: use **inner join** to get only these lines. Also use the full join syntax like: **select distinct eid,
               title 
from event LEFT JOIN e,review r ON  r.user=e.organizer or e.startdate>r.reviewdate;**

Answer (score 0):

If `event` in the table `review` references `eid` in the table `event`, you should base the join of the tables on these 2 columns (with an explicit join):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eid, title 
FROM event e INNER JOIN review r 
ON r.event = e.eid
WHERE e.organizer = r.user OR e.startdate > r.reviewdate;
```

You don't mention the table where the column `title` belongs.